# How do I launch a cmd prompt from another cmd prompt at the same location on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, terminal

In Mac, if I am in a *running* terminal window, running, say, a `jupyter notebook`, I can click `Cmd + n` to get a new terminal window at the same location. How do I do the same with command windows in Windows 10? If I have a running cmd window, how do I launch another command window with a single keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this isn't a keyboard shortcut, it is still very simple and fast:

If you type `start` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will open a new command prompt window in the same location.

Comment: Working in Windows PE or Recovery Mode with command-line only, and with only a single Command Line window, is a real pain. Thanks a lot, you just saved my day.